# why default check attribute is not working in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I want make radio button checked by default but it's not working in angular 6 when I use [(ngModel)]. It works fine as I expect in case of removing [(ngModel)]
my code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="user_type1"  name="user_type" class="custom-control-input" value="1" [(ngModel)]="form.user_type">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="user_type1">Vendor</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="user_type2" name="user_type" class="custom-control-input" value="2" [(ngModel)]="form.user_type">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="user_type2">Customer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I have also tried as

```
<input type="radio" id="user_type1" name="user_type" class="custom-control-input" value="1" [checked]="true"  [(ngModel)]="form.user_type" >
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[(ngModel)]` you are binding the checkbox value to `form.user_type` property value. So the `checked="true"` is ignored.

It is the correct behaviour because data binding has priority respect to static properties.

If you want to make the `checkbox` checked by default you need to match value property and `form.user_type`

**EDIT**

Try putting `value` attribute between square brackets like follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="user_type1"  name="user_type" class="custom-control-input" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="form.user_type">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="user_type1">Vendor</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="user_type2" name="user_type" class="custom-control-input" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="form.user_type">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="user_type2">Customer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: then how would I make it mutually exclusive?

Comment: because I have two radio buttons

Comment: what do you mean? do you need some as radio buttons?

Comment: please post your radio buttons code. they should share the same name attribute